# Выбор между GSAP и Velocity.js

Tags: jquery, анимация, javascript

Выбирала библиотеку для анимации, и выбор пал на [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap). Цель была найти универсальный инструмент для js анимации: для создания сложного баннера (вместо Flash), для множественных анимаций на странице, для анимации SVG. Все эти задачи GSAP решает превосходно и, главное, интуитивно просто. Одна проблема - библиотека весит 100кб. Новая библиотека - Velocity.js - весит всего! 7кб. Но функционал намного уже. По сути, это не полноценная библиотека, а jq плагин, рассчитанный на поочередные анимации. Теперь сижу и мучаюсь. Не хочется расставаться с GSAP ради легкого, но еще сырого инструмента с неясным будущим. Хотя его активно рекламируют на многих иностранных блогах, включая css-tricks.

Цель поста - спросить совета (прежде чем осваивать velocity), так ли уже будут эти 100кб скрипта критично влиять на перфонанс, и если да, то как можно это обойти (есть ли какие-нибудь оптимизаторы, ускорители и пр.). И в целом хочу узнать, какой инструмент реально больше используется в практике создания js анимации на коммерческих сайтах.

Заранее спасибо за ваше мнение и советы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Olga Moscow](/users/19681/olga-moscow)](/users/19681/olga-moscow), 100кб будут критично влиять, если целевая аудитория будет заходить с калькуляторов, так что бросьте. Смотрите только на то, насколько Вас устраивает функционал. В данном случае куда бóльшую роль играет конечная цель, которую вы хотите достигнуть.

В качестве оптимизаторов используйте минифиеры, коих в [гугле](http://pogugli.com/?72600) полно.

На практике используются самописные движки, т.к. в такие библиотеки закладывают слишком много функционала, который не используется. Библиотеки хорошо, когда много работы и мало времени. Или когда работа не по плечу.

Comment: @stck, большое спасибо за совет! На работе встал вопрос, чтобы баннеры "были такими же красивыми, как во Flash", вот и пришлось искать инструмент, который бы синхронизировал время  вложенных анимаций. Все это отлично делает GSAP и не умеет Velocity. А так динамику делаю на jq "руками". Я подумала, что неплохо еще Grunt освоить, он вроде делает тоже компрессию js. Спасибо за ответ, как гора с плеч:)

Comment: @Olga Moscow, раз Вы пишите на js, то gulp вам освоить будет куда проще. К тому же он умеет тот же стафф, что и grunt.

Comment: @stck, большое спасибо за совет! Так и сделаю!

Answer (score 0):

gasp около 30кб весит в Lite версии. Он приятный, хоть и не свободный.